# i want to replace the node name of a given node except for the innermost child nodes?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Input XML

```
<topicref outputclass="Dx:Appendix" href="appendix_topic_a.dita">
   <topicref outputclass="Dx:Appendix" href="appendix_topic_b.dita">
      <topicref outputclass="Dx:Appendix" href="appendix_topic_c.dita"/>
   </topicref>
   <topicref outputclass="Dx:Appendix" href="appendix_topic_d.dita">
     <topicref outputclass="Dx:Appendix" href="appendix_topic_e.dita"/>
   </topicref>    
</topicref>
<topicref outputclass="Dx:Appendix" href="appendix_topic_f.dita"/>
```

Output

```
<appendix class="Dx:Appendix" href="appendix_topic_a.dita">
   <appendix class="Dx:Appendix" href="appendix_topic_b.dita">
      <topicref class="Dx:Appendix" href="appendix_topic_c.dita"/>
   </appendix>
   <appendix class="Dx:Appendix" href="appendix_topic_d.dita">
     <topicref class="Dx:Appendix" href="appendix_topic_e.dita"/>
   </appendix>    
</appendix>
<appendix class="Dx:Appendix" href="appendix_topic_f.dita"/>
```

So basically I need to change the name of node `<topicref>` to `<appendix>` if it is not the innermost `<topicref>`. And if it is a standalone node like in case of `<topicref>` with `href="appendix_topic_f.dita"`, I need to change it to `<appendix>` which is a self closing tag.
Moreover the attribute name `outputclass` has to be changed to `class` keeping its value the same.

Comment: What exactly qualifies as "innermost" and what exactly does "standalone" mean? Your input is missing a root element. In a well-formed XML, only the root element can be truly "standalone".

Comment: by innermost i mean the <topicref> which has a parent node <topicref> but not the child node.  For your reference you can check out the <topicref> node with @href value ="appendix_topic_c.dita"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I take the liberty of restating your requirements as: change the name of `topicref` if:

- it has another `topicref` as a child; **or**
- its parent is not another `topicref`

then I arrive at:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="topicref[topicref or not(parent::topicref)]">
    <appendix>          
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </appendix>         
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to the following **well-formed** test input:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <topicref outputclass="Dx:Appendix" href="appendix_topic_a.dita">
        <topicref outputclass="Dx:Appendix" href="appendix_topic_b.dita">
            <topicref outputclass="Dx:Appendix" href="appendix_topic_c.dita"/>
        </topicref>
        <topicref outputclass="Dx:Appendix" href="appendix_topic_d.dita">
            <topicref outputclass="Dx:Appendix" href="appendix_topic_e.dita"/>
        </topicref>
    </topicref>
    <topicref outputclass="Dx:Appendix" href="appendix_topic_f.dita"/>
</root>
```

the **result** will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <appendix outputclass="Dx:Appendix" href="appendix_topic_a.dita">
    <appendix outputclass="Dx:Appendix" href="appendix_topic_b.dita">
      <topicref outputclass="Dx:Appendix" href="appendix_topic_c.dita"/>
    </appendix>
    <appendix outputclass="Dx:Appendix" href="appendix_topic_d.dita">
      <topicref outputclass="Dx:Appendix" href="appendix_topic_e.dita"/>
    </appendix>
  </appendix>
  <appendix outputclass="Dx:Appendix" href="appendix_topic_f.dita"/>
</root>
```

Comment: Moreover i want to change the name of the attribute outputclass to class. How can i do it ?

Comment: I thought I explained exactly what it does. What specifically do you not understand? -- Re your other question: add another template matching the attribute and rename it. This is a trivial task and has nothing to do with the main problem here.